# git how to move back commit

Tags: git, git-bash

I want to go back a committed one. How can I do?

```
$ git reflog
9b2a45e HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to HEAD~1
0c54f19 HEAD@{1}: reset: moving to HEAD~1
b9c157d HEAD@{2}: commit: updated from online
0c54f19 HEAD@{3}: commit: add img from download folder
9b2a45e HEAD@{4}: commit: add images
6fa6e34 HEAD@{5}: clone: from git@bitbucket.org:starpix/dojo.git


$ git reset --hard HEAD~1
HEAD is now at 9b2a45e add images
```

I want to go back to "updated from online". how can I?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`git checkout b9c157d` checks out the commit represented by the sha starting with `b9c157d` -- the commit you asked about.

Answer (score 9):

you can just move head forword to b9c157d

```
git reset --hard b9c157d
```

Comment: reset command would be the ideal one to use, so you can still get your branch to track your changes. you could use --soft or --mixed switches incase you want the skipped changes in your staging or working area, else --hard is good enough

Answer (score 1):

If you have the commit id of that particular commit then this syntax will do for you.

`git checkout commit_name` in the commit name pass the commit id and if you don't want to checkout again then to revert the commit will do by this one `git revert commit_name`.